# 'Blocked by CORS policy', but Header is present

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, go, cors

I created a REST API using Go and `fasthttp` and a frontend using Vue. Everytime I make an API request, I get the error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:55555/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` in my Browser console. The only time I don't get this error, is the `/auth/check` route. Also I made an OPTIONS-Request to my backend and got all the CORS Headers. I don't get them if I make a POST or GET request, but I don't know why.

**Backend:**

```golang
webRouter := router.New()

auth := webRouter.Group("/auth")
auth.GET("/check", authCheck)
auth.POST("/login", authLogin)
auth.GET("/logout", authCheck)

err = fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":"+port, func (ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type, set-cookie, cookie, server")
    ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
    ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false")
    webRouter.Handler(ctx)
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**Frontend request:**

```js
axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:55555'
}).post('/auth/login', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: can you please show the request headers and response headers that you see in your browser developer tools

Comment: What is the parameter in login method if string then parse the object to JSON.stringify and again convert to object in the serverside other wise check the oject field matching your passing object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue. I read the docs of fasthttp another time and figured out that the `ctx.Error()` method clears all headers. Instead I am now setting the response code and error message manually and everything works fine.